# Angular forms - submit only certain fields

Tags: angular

I have an Angular form that works correctly and submits all fields. However - I want to create a button that ONLY sends one field (username) to an endpoint to see if the username is available.

How do I only zero in on 1 field to perform an action?

Answer (score 1):

FYI Angular's really more powerful than that. You can use reactive form and write your own custom validator which checks if the `userName` is available in realtime without even pressing a button.

Example: Let's say you have a form like this

```
var form = this._formBuilder.group({
 userName:['',this.userNameValidator],
 password:''
 ... other fields
})
```

Here's how the validator takes place

```
userNameValidator(control:AbstractControl) {
 const userName = control.value;
 const isValidUserName = // do your necessary validation
 return isValidUserName ? {isValidUserName : false}:null;
}
```

More info : [Official Docs](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) and a [A nice blog](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/advanced-topics/basic-custom-validators/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `get` method to extract a specific control from a FormGroup

```
username = this.myForm.get('username')
```

Consider the below approach if you have implemented the Reactive Forms

In your TS file

```js
// Create a Subject Observable to track the click event
checkUserExistsSubject$ = new Subject();
checkUserExistsAction$ = checkUserExistsSubject$.asObservable();

// Declare your form using FormBuilder
myForm = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [Validators.required, ...]]
  ...
})

// Declare an observable to track the value changes
usernameChanged$ = this.myForm.get('username').valueChanges;

// Combine the two Observable using combineLatest from rxjs

checkUserExists$ = combineLatest([this.usernameChanged$, this.checkUserExistsAction$]).pipe(
  map(([username]) => username)
)
ngOnInit() {
  this.checkUserExists$.pipe(
    // Pipe the mergeMap/swithMap etc operator from rxjs/operators
    mergeMap(username => {

        // return the Observable calling
        return this.userService.checkUserExists(username)
      }
    )
  ).subscribe({
    next: (res) => {
      // Do something with the response
    }
  })
}
```

In your HTML file

```
<button (click)='checkUserExistsSubject$.next()' ... >Check User</button>
```